# R Markdown Shiny renderPlot list of plots from lapply

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, lapply, openair

I am developing an R Markdown Shiny document to:

1. Subset a data frame to include the "date" column and some numeric data columns. The way the shiny user input is set up, you select radio buttons for the data columns to include, then hit the "Subset Data" button to create `d()` - NO PROBLEM:)
2. Generate a list of plots (`plotList`), one for each numeric data column (plotted against the date column). I am using the `openair` package `timePlot` function to generate the plots, and `lapply` to generate the list of plot objects (`plotList`) - NO PROBLEM:)
3. use `renderPlot` to output all the plots in `plotList` to the R Markdown document - PROBLEM:(

I know there have been similar questions (e.g https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/, [Reactivity in R shiny with toy example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930144/reactivity-in-r-shiny-with-toy-example), and [dynamically add plots to web page using shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875786/dynamically-add-plots-to-web-page-using-shiny)), and please believe me I have tried and tried (e.g. using a for loop in stead of lapply-not my preference, but if it worked then who cares; adding local() and/or observe(); etc). No matter what I do I can't get it to to work. I am new to R Markdown and to Shiny, I just can't figure this out - please help!

Here is a reproducible example (to be run as an R markdown shiny document).

First the chunk that creates a reactive dataset `d()`:

````
```{r reactive-dataset, echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
library(openair)
library(dplyr)
data<-mydata[1:50,]
print(tbl_df(data))

inputPanel(
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId="p",
                label="select pollutants to plot",
                choices=names(data)[-1]
              ),
  actionButton(inputId="import",
               label="Subset Data")
)


d<-eventReactive(input$import,{
  d<-data %>% select(date,one_of(input$p))
  })

renderPrint({tbl_df(d())})
```
````

Now the second chunk, to create `plotList` and output it (PART THAT DOESN'T WORK):

Attempt 1: only last plot is displayed

````
 ```{r plot,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
 renderPlot({
  i<-names(d())[-1]
  tp<-function(x){
    p<-timePlot(d(),
         pollutant=print(x),
         main="Minute Validation",
         ylab="Minute Conc. (ug/m3 or ppb)",
         key=T)
    p$plot
    }
  lapply(i,tp)

  }) 
  ```
````

Attempt 2 (based on [Reactivity in R shiny with toy example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930144/reactivity-in-r-shiny-with-toy-example)). No plots are displayed

````
```{r plot,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
plotList<-reactive({
  i<-names(d())[-1]
  tp<-function(x){
    p<-timePlot(d(),
         pollutant=print(x),
         main="Minute Validation",
         ylab="Minute Conc. (ug/m3 or ppb)",
         key=T)
    p$plot
    }
  lapply(i,tp)
  })


observe({
  for (j in 1:length(plotList())){
    local({
      my_j<-j
      renderPlot({plotList()[[my_j]]})

      })#end local
    } #end for loop
}) #end observe
```
````

I have fiddled with this endlessly, referring the to similar questions that I have linked to above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[New answer]

I finally got this worked out. The key is to exactly follow the example in the third link of your post, using renderUI first!

````
```{r plot,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
tp_list <- reactive({
  i<-names(d())[-1]
  tp<-function(x){
    p<-timePlot(d(),
         pollutant=print(x),
         main="Minute Validation",
         ylab="Minute Conc. (ug/m3 or ppb)",
         key=T)
    p$plot
  }
  lapply(i, tp)
}) 

renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:length(tp_list()), function(i) {
        plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
        plotOutput(plotname)
    })
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
})

observe({
for (i in 1:length(tp_list())) {
    local({
        my_i <- i
        plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")
        output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
            tp_list()[[my_i]]
        })
    })
}
})
```
````

[Original answer based on lattice panels]

This is not exactly what you want, but I got all the plots displayed in one plot.

````
```{r plot,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
renderPlot({
  i<-names(d())[-1]
  tp<-function(x){
    p<-timePlot(d(),
         pollutant=print(x),
         main="Minute Validation",
         ylab="Minute Conc. (ug/m3 or ppb)",
         key=T)
    p$plot
  }
  tp(i)
}) 
```
````

Comment: Thanks for trying. I could generate the same plot as you have above by using `pollutant=names(d())[-1]` as an argument in timePlot and removing the function `tp` all together. The reason this won't work for me is because I need to plot many columns of data against date (>10) and having them all as separate panels in a single plot won't be desired, the data will be too compressed. I need them in separate plots.

Comment: You can set the image height to be dynamically adjusted based on number of panels.

Comment: That might work! Would you be able to provide an example code for how to do that? Ultimately, it would be useful for me to know how to make separate plots as I will have multiple applications (e.g. split data by pollutant, or by site, etc.). But can't be too picky given that I am totally stuck.

Comment: Updated my answer with a fully working example, multiple plots!

Comment: Yes!!! I don't totally understand what the renderUI does, but it works! thank you than you thank you!!!!!

Comment: Basically renderUI reserves a space for renderPlot to draw graphs. Please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: What is the `my_i <- i` part for?